# Runing 20 km after 10 days

Tags: long-distance-running

I am planing to participate in Spartan Race on 10th Nov.
What do you advice me to do during 10 days time before the race. Taking in consideration my max run was 10 K last week

Comment: Try this one (good guide to training for 12 months): https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/12930/4370

Comment: Doesn't completely apply to you, but it's virtually impossible to do enough training in 2 weeks to make a difference.